# Is there a good summary somewhere of what should go in each of the main folders in a linux install?

Tags: linux, directory, lsb

eg bin, sbin, proc, lib, boot, usr, etc...

Is there a standard list somewhere, does it depend on the distro?

This is essentially to answer the common question I have "I'm installing X or putting Y on the server, what folder should I put it in?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each distro may have their own quirks, but the overall file system structure should be more or less the same:

- ["Linux File Structure"](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/commands/linux_crfilest.html) is a good overview of the directory structure.
- ["Linux's directory structure"](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/linuxdir.html) is a bit more verbose and goes into more detail about their contents.

Answer (score 7):

If you're installing X or Y, and it's not a standard OS package, then stuff should end up in `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/lib/`, etc.

The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) and [Linux Standard Base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base) is probably a good place to start if you want to reference the closest thing there is to a standard list.